# Regular expression to get number between two bars

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a code that takes a certain url:

```
url = 'https://www.site.com.br/categoria-produto/category/page/3/? 
gclid=Cjkdksjkcm35522'

last_page = url
if last_page.split("page")[1]:
    t = last_page.split("page")[1]
    print(last_page)
```

return me a list,

however the list depending on what the url looks like may have a value of / 3 / or / 23 / as I have no way of knowing the value that will come between these two bars, ie one or two positions or even three positions. The only way I thought was to use regular expressions, but I don't know how to assemble the expression.

Detail: If I try to get the print position (last_page [1:4]) and only have 1 decimal place between the two // will get the bar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your code snippet doesn't "return" anything, it prints it. It does not print a list, it prints a string. What "bars" are you talking about? Are you just trying to extract the number that comes after the string `page/`?

Comment: yes, yes perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the page number then this pattern should do the trick.

```py
url = 'https://www.site.com.br/categoria-produto/category/page/3/?gclid=Cjkdksjkcm35522'
pg_num = re.search(r'page/([0-9]+)/', url).group(1)
# pg_num = '3'
```